# Can I still use yarn or npm to install a package in an Expo app's node_modules?

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, yarnpkg

I created an Expo project because I thought it would be easier to the person I'm teaching to code in React Native. But my instinct is to just use yarn or npm. Am I damaging project structure in any way?

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.expo.dev/workflow/using-libraries/#using-expo-sdk-libraries

> The `npx expo install` command will pick a version of the library that is compatible with your project and then use your JavaScript package manager (such as npm) to install it.

You could use `npm` or `yarn` directly if you want to, but if you use `npx expo install` it will just make sure that any known package compatibility is handled.